# Why is the Cholesky decomposition preferred to sqrtm in filtering algorithms?

Tags: linear-algebra, parameter-estimation, kalman-filter

Many nonlinear filtering algorithms like UKF and CKF make use of Cholesky decomposition. Whay can't we go for $sqrtm(P)$, such that $SS=P$, rather than $SS^{T}=P$? I have seen many answers stating that Cholesky reduces computational time and is light on storage space. Are there any other reasons?

Comment: "reduced computational time and light on storage space" are already two pretty good reasons, do you really need more?

Comment: I would be happy to hear more reasons. Thanks!!